Django debug toolbar is not displayed
I just installed debug toolbar for my django project like allways.
but I don't know why doesn't the debug toolbar display?!
and I have to add that I'm using docker and it's my first time that use docker.
I think I should do something with docker...
I also run "docker-compose up --build"
but nothing and nothing
